# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 101

Tags: java

I am trying to see the contents of an array, but when I run it comes an error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 101
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?
here is my code:

```
public final class KonversiQtoH extends DebitDiberikan{

public KonversiQtoH() throws SQLException{
    QBeriPintu1();
}
Connection c = KoneksiDatabase.getKoneksi();
Float[] fine;
public void QBeriPintu1() throws SQLException{
    try{
        List rowValues = new ArrayList();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT LA40 from tabel_debit";
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            rowValues.add(rs.getFloat("LA40"));
        }
        rs.close();
        s.close();
        fine = (Float[]) rowValues.toArray(new Float[rowValues.size()]);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("QKanan, error");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
    KonversiQtoH j = new KonversiQtoH();
    j.QBeriPintu1();
    for (int i=0; i<=j.fine.length; i++){
        int a = i+1;
        System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/754550

Comment: check your `main` method in loop you used `<=` which means greater than equals to the length of array. but index is accessible to `length-1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

The following line produces errors:

```
for (int i=0; i<=j.fine.length; i++) {
```

Replace with:

```
for (int i=0; i<j.fine.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the problematical code:

```
for (int i=0; i <= j.fine.length; i++) {
    int a = i+1;
    System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
}
```

Arrays in Java are indexed from *zero* to the length *minus one*.  The above loop actually tries to access one beyond the length of the array.  Fixing the bounds should get rid of this error:

```
for (int i=0; i < j.fine.length; i++){
    int a = i+1;
    System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change here

```
for (int i=0; i<=j.fine.length; i++){
        int a = i+1;
        System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
    }
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<j.fine.length; i++){
        int a = i+1;
        System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
    }
```

Comparison operatore from <= to <

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the "="
i<=j.fine.length

```
for (int i=0; i<j.fine.length; i++){
    int a = i+1;
    System.out.println(a+". "+j.fine[i]);
}
```